# Login into windows from .NET application

Tags: c#, .net, windows, authentication

I think it should be a windows service. when given certain conditions it should perform a login into the machine.

The machine will be in the "login screen" checking a webservice to know who is the user and password it should use to login.

Can this be done?, I don't want "automatic login" windows feature.

Thanks!

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific.  Your question just doesn't make much sense as is.  What is the purpose of this?  Can you describe the use case?

Comment: It would be use to login users into a machine from a remote location, without the need for the users to know the username or password, its a complex idea... i know!! :)

Comment: Are you trying to log remote users into machines automatically via Remote Desktop?  Or are you trying to log in a user at the console automatically from remote?

Comment: 2º, trying to login a user on the local machine from remote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK this cannot be done as the login/authentication is done by the [GINA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_identification_and_authentication) layer (Graphical Interface and Authentication), you're effectively trying to replace that layer with your own, which would not be feasible from the managed side of code. In short, the only way to develop a replacement for the GINA layer would have to be done from the C/C++ side, not for reasons of speed, but because of the complexity involved in programming, a new GINA subsystem which would have to take into account of

- Handling the authentication by interacting with WinLogon
- Setting up a desktop
- Loading Explorer as the shell

Doing it from .NET would not be a viable way of doing it. But nonetheless, if you are interested in replacing GINA with your own in pure C/C++ way, have a look here in the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163803.aspx) Magazine which published an article by Keith Brown, about replacing GINA with your own, in the May 2005 issue.

**Edit:** Thanks to ***Ruddy*** for pointing out this that I was not aware of, GINA has been replaced in Vista/Windows 7. Now, my view and of course this answer has changed to account for this accordingly, in short, to fulfill your goal and of course, to make this authentication backward if so wish for earlier version of Windows, ie XP (This may not be in your case, but worth mentioning). In Vista/Windows 7, GINA is replaced by a 'Content Provider', which I do not know about. But however, I have found this link to the MSDN about this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163489.aspx). ***Salvador*** - sorry if I cannot answer more about it as that's a new one to me! :(

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: Thank you very much Tom. Your information has been very helpful.

Comment: GINA is not applicable to Vista or Win7 anymore see "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_identification_and_authentication"

Comment: you had a quote at the end of the URL ... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_identification_and_authentication

Comment: @Matthew: Funny... I checked the url and it is ok...can you edit my answer to verify the link as I checked it and it appears ok! :(

Comment: Guess I should of note pointed out that I was saying that to @Ruddy.  He put quotes around this URL and the ending quote stuck to the link (Then again I am forced to use IE6 here at work... and  maybe that is why I see the problem even if others don't)

Comment: Then the question is how can I create a Credential Providers Plugin or similar?

Comment: I will edit my answer to include the mentioned link! Thanks Ruddy... :)

Comment: Thank you all very much. Tom, this helped me a lot!.

Comment: I just found this, very helpful. http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=b1b3cbd1-2d3a-4fac-982f-289f4f4b9300&displaylang=en

Comment: Sorry about the quotes ... normally i would put the title of the referenced page in the quotes and make it a hyperlink to the proper page in an answer... but i haven't quite figured out how to do that in a comment yet...